# Spring: How to avoid InvalidMimeTypeException in WFS request ("text/xml; subtype=gml/2.1.2")

Tags: java, spring, mime-types, gml, media-type

I'm getting a response from a WFS service and the following error is returned.
It seems this MediaType is not supported.

```
org.springframework.http.InvalidMediaTypeException: Invalid mime type "text/xml; subtype=gml/2.1.2": Invalid token character '/' in token "gml/2.1.2"
at org.springframework.http.MediaType.parseMediaType(MediaType.java:370)
at org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.getContentType(HttpHeaders.java:550)
at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.getContentType(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:116)
at org.springframework.web.client.HttpMessageConverterExtractor.extractData(HttpMessageConverterExtractor.java:87)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:809)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate$ResponseEntityResponseExtractor.extractData(RestTemplate.java:793)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:572)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:530)
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.postForEntity(RestTemplate.java:357)
```

...

```
Caused by: org.springframework.util.InvalidMimeTypeException: Invalid mime type "text/xml; subtype=gml/2.1.2": Invalid token character '/' in token "gml/2.1.2"
at org.springframework.util.MimeTypeUtils.parseMimeType(MimeTypeUtils.java:250)
at org.springframework.http.MediaType.parseMediaType(MediaType.java:367)
```

I have seen [How to overcome Invalid token character caused by Content-Type=[text/xml; subtype=gml/2.1.2] in Spring HttpMessageConverterExtractor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20508804/how-to-overcome-invalid-token-character-caused-by-content-type-text-xml-subtyp), but I'm not able to adapt this solution to my approach: I'm not using XML based, nor a spring integration based solution.

My code fragment:

```
RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
String url = "http://some.geo.server/wfs?";
String query = buildWFSSpatialQuery(geometry, type);
ResponseEntity<String> entity = template.postForEntity(url, query, String.class);
```

Where `query` is something like

```
<wfs:GetFeature service="WFS" version="1.0.0" maxFeatures="1" xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc" xmlns:gml="http://www.opengis.net/gml"><wfs:Query ....
```

The error can be very easily reproduced:

```
org.springframework.http.MediaType.parseMediaType("text/xml; subtype=gml/2.1.2");
```

Comment: I found a solution in http://stackoverflow.com/a/8101473/4827363. Use `setDefaultResponseContentType("text/xml; subtype=\"gml/2.1.2\"")`.

Answer (score 0):

OK there is a way to do it. What ya gotta do is use...

```
setDefaultResponseContentType("text/xml; subtype=\"gml/2.1.2\"")
```